Table doesn't fit in the page and add figure into the table's cell
Question:
I Prepared a table from online. The issue is it doesn't fit in the page. Second problem is I added codes for a figure , I want to add this figure in the first column (Second cell). Can anyone help me? How to increase height of the cell for center alignment?
MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%  Table  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|cccc|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Closure Property}}                                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-5} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Operation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Y/N}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Result}}                                            & \textbf{Remarks or Justification}          \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Natural Numbers}}           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Addition}           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Yes}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Natural number $+$ Natural number $=$ Natural number}       &                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Subtraction}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{No}           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Natural number $-$ Natural number $\neq$ Natural number}    & $2-5=-3$ and  $-3$ is not a natural number \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multiplication}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Yes}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Natural number $\times$ Natural number $=$ Natural number}  &                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Division}           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{No}           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Natural number $\div$ Natural number $\neq$ Natural number} & $2\div 5$, which is not a Natural number   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%  Figure  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=1.5,
            transform shape,
            txt/.style={align=center,font=\bfseries\sf\tiny},
            ]
\foreach \x/\clr in {1/blue!20}
\draw[color=black,very thick,fill=\clr] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x];
\node[txt] at (0,1) {Natural Numbers\\\\1, 2, 3, \dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


First step: remove all these troublesome multicolumns these terrible online table generators use. Once you have removed them, you can use fixed width columns to better fit your table in the page.

I removed the multicolumn but am getting errors. stuck in the middle.

Please update the code in your question

With tabularray:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tblr}{
     colspec={Q[l,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
     hlines, vlines,
     row{1,2}={font=\bfseries},
     cell{3,5}{3}={green},
     cell{4,6}{3}={red},
     }
     \SetCell[r=2]{c}Set & \SetCell[c=4]{c,red} Closure Property &&& \\  
     & Operation & Y/N & Result & Remarks or Justification \\ 
     \SetCell[r=4]{c}{Natural Numbers\\[7pt]
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
                scale=1.5,
                transform shape,
                txt/.style={align=center,font=\bfseries\sf\tiny},
                ]
     \foreach \x/\clr in {1/blue!20}
     \draw[color=black,very thick,fill=\clr] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x];
     \node[txt] at (0,1) {Natural Numbers\\\\1, 2, 3, \dots};
     \end{tikzpicture}} &  Addition & Yes & Natural number $+$ Natural number $=$ Natural number & \\ 
     & Subtraction & No & Natural number - Natural number $\neq$ Natural number & $2-5=-3$ and  $-3$ is not a Natural number \\ 
     & Multiplication & Yes & Natural number $\times$ Natural number $=$ Natural number  & \\
     & Division & No & Natural number $\div$ Natural number $\neq$ Natural number & $2\div 5$, which is not a Natural number \\ 
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Actually this figure was drawn from multiple circles. By mistake it was left. Thanks for correcting me and big thanks for your help.

I want to ask one question. How can I give color to a particular cell of the table? For example, how do you assign a red color to a cell with the text closure property?

@SandyM You can use \SetCell[c=4]{c,red} before the cell text. I will update my answer asap.

Thank you so much. I have tried it and it is working. I just want to ask how I can assign the red color to No and the green color to Yes.

@SandyM You could use \SetCell{red} before "No" or \SetCell{green} before "Yes". Alternatively, you can use cell{<row>}{<column>}={<color>}, see my renewed answer.

Wonderful. Thanks again

@SandyM You're welcome!

EDIT: Put the figure in the table.

As @samcarter noticed: remove the \multicolumn{1} stuff.
Use \small to make the text a bit smaller.
Replace Natural Number in the fourth column by an abbreviation because it takes up way too much space. Otherwise you'll never fit the table to your text width (unless you do line breaking in this column but I think that isn't nice at all). It's your choice, however.
Use tabularx to fit the last column in the available space. Or if you want to keep the full text in the fourth column, use a X column there too.
I used `\multirow{6} for the picture, as it actually spans 6 lines.

With some minor tweaks it becomes:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%  Table  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[]
  \small
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{\,}c@{\,}|c|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Set}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Closure Property}}                                        \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & \textbf{Operation} & \textbf{Y/N} & \textbf{Result}                    & \textbf{Remarks or Justification}          \\ \hline
        \multirow{6}{*}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=1.5,
            transform shape,
            txt/.style={align=center,font=\bfseries\sf\tiny},
            ]
\foreach \x/\clr in {1/blue!20}
\draw[color=black,very thick,fill=\clr] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x];
\node[txt] at (0,1) {Natural Numbers\\\\1, 2, 3, \dots};
\end{tikzpicture}}
        & Addition           & Yes          & NatNum $+$ NatNum $=$ NatNum       &                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & Subtraction        & No           & NatNum $-$ NatNum $\neq$ NatNum    & $2-5=-3$ and  $-3$ is not a natural number \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & Multiplication     & Yes          & NatNum $\times$ NatNum $=$ NatNum  &                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & Division           & No           & NatNum $\div$ NatNum $\neq$ NatNum & $2\div 5$, which is not a natural number   \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}



I had forgotten about the figure in the table. It is there now.
